# Getting a more precise selection of target from the mousemove event

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, mouseevent

I'm currently developing a Chrome Extension and a part of that is having items highlighted as the user mouses over them, much like that of the developer DOM selector tools build into the browser.

Currently I've been able to impliment two solutions, one that adds and removes a border to the item thats being selected, this works really well actually but ive been trying to do it with an overlay too. Currently I have a semi working solution for the overlay but it's no where near as accurate or as good as the border. Basically I have this code so far for the border:

The idea with this solution is to grab the mouseover event, find what element the mouse is over and insert a div thats semi transparent inside filling up the same size, and then remove it after

```
var overlay =  $('<div></div>',{id: "8b29f35f-6cc6"});
$(overlay).css(({
    position: 'absolute',
    display:'block',
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    top: '0',
    left: '0',
    right: '0',
    bottom: '0',
    background: 'rgba(55,22,124,0.5)',
    zindex: '1000000',
    cursor: 'pointer'}));

var CurrentItem;
$('body').mousemove(function(evt){
    CurrentItem = evt.target
});
```

```
selecting = setInterval(function(){
    $("#8b29f35f-6cc6").remove();
    currentElement = CurrentItem;
    $(currentElement).append(overlay);
}, 100);
```

However with this approach lots of elements aren't getting the overlay and often with sites like for example stack overflow the overlay is just [image]going straight over most of the content and not smaller indivial DOM elements. as shown below, you cant really see because the mouse isnt shown but basically its always going for much bigger DOM elements over the small ones im actually moused over

Comment: Try adding `pointerEvents: 'none'` in css(), and I think your zindex doesn't work because it should be zIndex or 'z-index'. You'll also have to set `top` and `left` and `width` and `height` explicitly by calculating getBoundingClientRect for example, because currently they don't work: they need the parent element to have `position:relative`.